# Vue.js get all v-model bindings

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

With Vue.js you can you bind form input to a property:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

I am working on a project where I 'dynamically' generate a form though. Here the v-model bindings are just attributes that are being set based on the name that an input has.

The problem though is that I am left wondering how to properly get these v-model bindings. So far all I have see is people manually setting a property on their Vue instance for the binding:

```
new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  }
})
```

Is it possible to somehow grab all of the `v-model` bindings though without setting up the data properties manually?

When creating a dynamic form with a variation an dynamic number of fields this would help out a lot.

I guess one option is simply retrieving the name atributes from the input with javascript but I am hoping there might be something in place already since `v-model` is probably calling a setter that might already be known in the Vue instance.

**Reworked the example from the answer:**

https://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2477/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

> it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the `Vue.set(object, key, value)` method.

This means that your starting `data` can be something like:

```
{
  customForm: [],
  values: {}
}
```

Let's assume `customForm` is an array of field objects that describe a bunch of fields in your custom form. It's empty at the beginning because you say your form will be created dynamically.

Once you generate that dynamic data, all you need to do is assign it to `customForm` and loop through it to add reactive properties with the aforementioned `Vue.set` method.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2451/) with an example. I'm using `this.$set`, but that's just an alias for `Vue.set`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just as an aside, the `values` model can be re-assigned as follows: `this.values = myNewForm.reduce((model, field) => { model[field.id] = ''; return model }, {});`

Comment: You are rendering a form from an array specified in Vue.js itself though. Is it possible to do the same when you are simply hooking up Vue to a pre-defined HTML form? I am trying to refactor the JSFiddle but I am unsure if this is even going to work. Thanks for helping out so far!

Comment: Never mind, got the answer based off your example: https://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2477/